# Посоветуйте книги/статьи по анализу аномалий

Tags: анализ-данных, анализ

Всем привет,
посоветуйте , пожалуйста,  книгу/статью по анализу аномалий. Задача такая: есть масса показателей по работе ЖКХ( финансирование, строительство, реконструкция и т.д.), нужно определить аномалии. Например, прокладывание труб стало сильно дороже, чем обычно на каком-либо участке. Или сделана одна и та же работа дважды. Конечная цель-сделать работу РСО более прозрачной.

Comment: Обычно такую работу выполняет специальный аналитик. Либо тренировать нейронку, но предварительно предоставив данные для нее от того же аналитика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выявление аномалий - это ОГРОМНЫЙ, к тому-же разветвленный раздел DataScience. Вряд-ли вам хватит одной статьи или даже книги. Это я не говорю о том, что судя по всему, вы даже Гуугл самостоятельно пользоваться почему-то не хотите). А следовательно, вам будет очень трудно находить ответы на сотни вопросов, которые будут возникать при попытке решить какую-нибудь реальную задачу.

То, что вы описываете - это тянет на целый проект и не решается походя вопросами на форуме. Что бы вы себе представляли - задачи поиска аномалий рассматриваются в рамках таких разделов Machine Learning, как Анализ временных рядов, Классификация и кластерный анализ, Нейросети, Статистический анализ данных и др. Кроме всего прочего, с практической  стороны эти задачи рассматриваются в Технической диагностике, Медицинской диагностике, Финансовом анализе, Анализе сетевого трафика и пр.  И в каждом учебнике или книге есть разделы, так или иначе связанные с указанной вами темой.

Но тем не менее, для того, чтобы дать хоть какой-то толчок в нужном направлении - вот вам несколько "стартовых" источников.

Charu C. Aggarwal Outlier Analysis. 2017

Jie Chen, Arjun K. Gupta Parametric Statistical Change Point Analysis and Finance. Springer,2012

Ted Dunning, Ellen Friedman. Practical Machine Learning. A New    Look at Anomaly Detection. 2014.

Manish Gupta. Outlier Detection for Temporal Data, 2014

Samuel Hugueny. Novelty Detection with Extreme Value Theory in Vital-Sign Monitoring,2013.

Preetam Jinka, Baron Schwartz. Anomaly Detection for Monitoring. A Statistical Approach to Time Series Anomaly Detection. 2015.

Kishan G. Mehrotra , Chilukuri K. Mohan, HuaMing Huang Anomaly Detection Principles and Algorithms. 2017.

Бассвиль М. Обнаружение изменения свойств сигналов в динамических системах.

Кравцов Ю. МОДЕЛИ, АЛГОРИТМЫ И ПРОГРАММЫ ОБНАРУЖЕНИЯ НАРУШЕНИЙ ПРИ МНОГОМЕРНОМ СТАТИСТИЧЕСКОМ КОНТРОЛЕ ПРОЦЕССА. 2015.

Никифоров И.В. Последовательное обнаружение изменения свойств временных рядов.

Суханов А. ИНТЕЛЛЕКТУАЛЬНЫЕ МЕТОДЫ ОБНАРУЖЕНИЯ И ПРОГНОЗИРОВАНИЯ АНОМАЛЬНЫХ СОБЫТИЙ В ТЕМПОРАЛЬНЫХ ДАННЫХ, 2015.

Белоусов П. Разработка и применение методовобнаружения изменения свойств и прогнозирования временных рядов в задачах диагностирования.

И еще сотни других источников. Все легко гууглиться в интернет.
Как появятся конкретные вопросы - возвращайтесь, задавайте, будем рады помочь.

Comment: что значит Гуглом не хочу пользоваться? 
Я задала этот вопрос, в надежде получить стоящую книгу/ статью именно по моему запросу. В  интернете огромное множество литературы и прочесть все не хватит ни времени , ни сил. Для этого и существуют форумы, разве нет? Спасибо за подборку:)

Comment: Тем более я написала область в которой рассматривается задача, и это не медицина, анализ сетевого трафика и т.д.

Comment: Вы серьезно рассчитываете найти книгу "Поиск Аномалий в ЖКХ"?  Вы же понимаете(надеюсь, после ознакомления с тем, что вы сумели самостоятельно найти и прочитать в интернете), что решения конкретной вашей задачи вы все равно нигде не найдете и что вам придется применять одновременно много разных существующих методов посика аномалий, анализировать, сравнивать их и пр. -  то (повторюсь)"Вряд-ли вам хватит одной статьи или даже книги". И добавлю -  умение искать решения своей задачи, анализируя задачи "медицины, анализы сетевого трафика и т.д" -  один из важнейших навыков специалиста этой области.